# Как создать и уничтожить view

Tags: view

Суть такова, что при стаhте должна появляться view за 30 поинтов до основной view. После прохождения экрана(основного view) через 30 поинтов после экрана(основной view) начальную view надо уничтожить. И данный процесс необходимо повторять постоянно. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: С такими вопросами вас просто заминусуют и помогать никто не станет. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask как задавать хорошие вопросы! И переформулируйте в соответствии к правилам сообщества.

Comment: я бы добавил какие-нибудь тэги технологий и в название тоже. каждый программист - специалист в какой-то области. а тут не понятно, может это winforms или фронтенд на html? соответственно и ответы будут разные.

Comment: Понял исправлю. Спасибо за советы.